# HP ZBook 15 G3 keyboard randomly repeats in Linux VMs Hyper-V AND vbox

Tags: laptop, keyboard, virtual-machine

- **GIVEN** an HP ZBook 15 G3 running latest Windows 10.
- **AND** running a graphical virtual machine

  - **EITHER** Hyper-V CentOS
  - **OR** Hyper-V Ubuntu
  - **OR** virtualbox CentOS
- **WHEN** typing with built-in keyboard
- **THEN** keys will RANDOMLY repeat

**WORKAROUND** Disable key repeat in guest keyboard settings

Using linux with either randomly repeating keys OR no key repeat is incredibly frustrating to say the least. Note that adjusting the key repeat delay does nothing to fix this. I think I can avoid it by typing carefully like on a typewriter, but it's like walking on eggshells.

Sure there are plenty of similar sounding bug reports about this all over the place, but the specific problem is always flooded by "me too"s that are a different problem.

This actually seems like a bug at the Windows host / Linux guest driver level that is somehow independent of whether its Hyper-V or virtualbox

**QUESTION** Has anyone had this exact problem with key repeat only happening in VMs on laptop keyboards, and have you found a solution?